# Y-axis Scale Number in the Millions

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

[image: Image created from the code->]
I am trying to edit the Y-axis scale to represent the amount the rows of Id. The numbers needed to be shown on the scale are in the millions. I need to abbreviate the number in order for it to be seen on the visualization.

```
  ggplot(sleeptocalories1, aes(Id,TotalCalories) +
  geom_col(fill="steelblue") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 45))
```

Comment: What abbreviation do you seek?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like `scales::label_number_si()`:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 10^(2:6)), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_number_si())
```

[image]

On your data, it might be:

```
ggplot(sleeptocalories1, aes(Id,TotalCalories) +
  geom_col(fill="steelblue") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 45)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_number_si())
```

Comment: When using this method; I receive "Error in sleeptocalories1(x = Id, y = 10^(2:6)) : 
  could not find function "sleeptocalories1"."

Comment: My `data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 10^(2:6)` was meant as a replacement for your data, which I don't have. You'd only need to add the `scale_y_continuous` line.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to convert the labels to millions via the `labels` argument of `scale_y_continuous`.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
set.seed(123)
sleeptocalories1 <- data.frame(
  Id = 1:10,
  TotalCalories = runif(10, 86, 12e6)
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(sleeptocalories1, aes(Id, TotalCalories)) +
  geom_col(fill = "steelblue") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = ~ .x / 1e6) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 45))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I can use the single digit numbers to represent calories by millions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `scales` library can help with formatting the scales of plots. Scientific notation is an abbreviation.

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
```

```
demo_continuous(c(0, 1e9), labels = label_number_auto())
```

[image]

May not be appropriate for this application, but log breaks are also possible

```r
demo_log10(c(1, 1e5), labels = label_log())
```

[image]